# Can not login to superset after installing it on AWS kuberbetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, apache-superset

I installed amancevice/superset to AWS Kubernetes.
When i open Load balancer DNS, I can see superset login page but default login is not working admin/admin.
Is there anything i missed?

Here's my yaml file i used to install superset

`Superset.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: superset-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: superset
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: superset
    spec:
      containers:
      -  name: superset
         image: amancevice/superset:latest
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8088
```

`kubectl create -f superset.yaml`

Comment: Did you install csi driver on the eks, setup postgress etc or did you just create the superset pod, loadbalancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialize the database with an admin user, Run superset-init helper script

```
kubectl exec -it superset superset-init
```

MoreDetails [Here](https://github.com/amancevice/docker-superset/blob/main/README.md#database-initialization)